# Alternative to xsd.exe in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xsd

Looks like XSD.exe is not delivered as a part of Visual Studio 2010.

what is the alternative being offered in VS2010?

Comment: Exists in my install of the Windows 7 SDK (which if not with 2010 can be downloaded separately), which should be mostly appropriate. Not sure why a default install of 2010 wouldn't come with it though.

Comment: Just in case you don't know where the default directory for the Windows SDK is (I didn't before), mine was at 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\{version number}'.  The 'bin' directory has all of the binaries.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's available from the VS 2010 command prompt.   Open up the VS 2010 command prompt and type "xsd /?".

Comment: Thanks CleturLoomis, but it tells me "Command "xsd" is not valid.". To open the command window I used either View -> Other Windows -> Command Window or Ctrl + W, A

Comment: I have VS2010 Professional and do not have access to this command.

Comment: tobsen, kwelch, seems you are trying to use xsd command in Command window of Visual Studio.
Dean is talking about Visual Studio command prompt, which you can open from Start Menu (Start Menu -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)

Answer (score 18):

Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt

You can use xsd.exe from here.

Answer (score 16):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\xsd.exe

Answer (score 4):

I believe xsd.exe is not available with Visual Studio * 2010 Express

Comment: I believe you are right.  I just installed Express and xsd.exe is NOT at this path.

Answer (score 4):

**XML Schema Definition Tool** is available in the menu **"Start"**:

**Start-> All Programs-> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010-> Visual Studio Command Prompt(2010)**

You'll see the welcome message a command line:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>
```

You can, for example, create an **XML** scheme from the **XML**-file.

***example.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<country>
    <country_name>France</country_name>
    <population>59.7</population>
</country>
```

To do this, enter the following:

```
I:\example.xml /outputdir:D:\xml2xsd
```

In my system, i see the following:

```
...
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'D:\xml2xsd\example.xsd'.

D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>
```

In the catalog `D:\xml2xsd\` came a such a scheme:

***example.xsd:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="country">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="country_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="population" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="country" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

A full list of options here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx

As for alternatives, you can search converters for operations that allows xsd.exe:

- XDR to XSD
- XML to XSD
- XSD to DataSet
- XSD to Classes
- Classes to XSD

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add this to my path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\
```

(Start > Edit the system environment variables > Environment Variables > Edit 'Path' under 'System variables')

Then I could start the Visual Studio command prompt (2010) and type

```
xsd.exe /?
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking DTD is an alternative to XSD and DTD is fully supported in Visual Studio. However, DTD is a weaker language, as some things can not be expressed in it. For example, it does not support as many data types as XSD does, nor does it have assertions. Anyways, if you're not too picky about it, you can give it a try.

Comment: He means what is the alternative to the xsd.exe tool, not to the xsd schema language.